# Custom string sorting in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, sorting

I have an array that I want sorted alphabetically (for the most part). For example I want an array of string to be sorted A-Z with the exception of elements starting with "g", I want elements starting with "g" to be last (or first if that's easier) in the array.

Example:

```
let list = ["apple", "car", "boat", "zebra", "ghost", "far"]
```

sorted should be:

```
["apple", "boat", "car", "far", "zebra", "ghost"]
```

How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sorted(by:)` and compare cases that start with "g" and then fallback to normal `String` comparison if that doesn't happen:

```
let sorted = list.sorted { a, b in
    if a.first == "g" && b.first != "g" { return false }
    if b.first == "g" && a.first != "g" { return true }
    return a < b
}
```

Comment: I think a single expression such as `(!$0.hasPrefix("g") && $1.hasPrefix("g")) || (!$0.hasPrefix("g") && $0 < $1)` works too, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would split it into 2 arrays, sort each of them, then combine them again.

```
let list = ["apple", "car", "boat", "zebra", "ghost", "far"]
let listWithoutG = list.filter { !$0.hasPrefix("g") }
let listOnlyG = list.filter { $0.hasPrefix("g") }

let sorted = listWithoutG.sorted() + listOnlyG.sorted()
print("Sorted: \(sorted)")
```

Result:

```
Sorted: ["apple", "boat", "car", "far", "zebra", "ghost"]
```